# Excel Script // "lineCSV is not iterable"

Tags: excel, power-automate, office-scripts

I am trying to create a powerautomate flow that converts CSV Files into Excel Files once received by E-Mail by a Tutorial on Youtube, unfortunately when i try to run the Script it shows the Error "Line 5: lineCSV is not iterable"

below the code i am trying to get working, i am new to excel scripts so sorry if i ask one more question then others.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, lineCSV: string[]) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    const alllines = lineCSV;
    let counter = 1;
    for (let line of lineCSV) {
        if (line.includes(";")) {
            let items = line.split(";");
            selectedSheet.getRange("A1" + counter + ":I1" + counter).setValues([[items[0], items[1], items[2], items[3], items[4], items[5], items[6], items[7], items[8], items[9], items[10], items[11], items[12], items[13], items[14], items[15], items[16], items[17], items[18], items[19], items[20], items[21], items[22], items[23], items[24], items[25]]]);
            counter++;
            // Set range A1:AL2 on selectedSheet
            selectedSheet.getRange("A" + counter+";AL"+counter).setValues([[items[0], items[1], items[2], items[3], items[4], items[5], items[6], items[7], items[8], items[9], items[10], items[11], items[12], items[13], items[14], items[15], items[16], items[17], items[18], items[19], items[20], items[21], items[22], items[23], items[23], items[24], items[25], items[26], items[27], items[28], items[29], items[30], items[31], items[32], items[33], items[34], items[35], items[36], items[37]
]]);
            counter++;
    }

}
    // Add a new table at range A1:AL2 on selectedSheet
    workbook.addTable(selectedSheet.getRange("A1:AL2" + counter), true).setName ("PARKER PREADVISE");
}
```

Wanted to convert CSV Files into an Excel Workbook, when running the script it shows an error